# Apache CXF logging SOAP message

Tags: xml, cxf

I have an Apache CXF webservice. I need to log the formatted soap messages, each message in separate file, in the filename I have to use values of particular xml tags.
First I implemented SOAPHandler I got the javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage object and my logging algorithm worked fine. The only problem was that my service bean seemed to be skipped. I tried to use implementations of AbstractSoapInterceptor and AbstractLoggingInterceptor, but find difficult to get values of particular xml tags. Searching for the solution I found so many implementations of org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Interceptor that I became confused. I would like to ask what would be the proper solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you write to file inside your ws implementation file. Since You are concerned about few parameters. i don't find the advatnage of interceptors and it will be thread safe as well

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In what way should I write the whole xml string inside the ws implementation file?

Comment: Add a subclass of AbstractPhaseInterceptor like so: https://github.com/greenbird/xml-formatter-components/blob/master/cxf/src/main/java/com/greenbird/xmlformatter/cxf/XMLLoggingInInterceptor.java. Replace line 123-145 with your own logic.